# Change of the coordinates in expression

Tags: calculus, education, polar-coordinates, jacobian, change-of-variable

How can I simplify

$$x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=r^2\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial r^2},$$

by changing coordinates from Cartesian to polar coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto(r,\varphi)$, $u(x,y)=g(r,\varphi)$ ?

Comment: Is your last term supposed to include both $u$ and $g$?

Comment: I have corrected it now. Thank you. could you help me?

Comment: I am struggling. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chain rule. And it's easier to start from the right hand side. We use $$x=r\cos\varphi\\y=r\sin\varphi$$
Then we calculate the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $r$:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dr}=\cos\varphi\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin\varphi\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
We apply the formula again to get the second derivative:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial r^2}&=\cos\varphi\frac{\partial}{dx}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}+\sin\varphi\frac{\partial}{dy}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}\\&=\cos\varphi(cos\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\sin\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y})+\sin\varphi(cos\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\sin\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2})\\&=\cos^2\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2\sin\varphi\cos\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\sin^2\varphi\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\end{align}$$
Now multiply with $r^2$ both sides, and you get your answer.

Comment: thank you !!why do I have to multiply with r^2?

Comment: Because you have $r^2\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r^2}$, not just $\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r^2}$

Comment: so the final answer will be the last like you wrote multiplied by r^2 = to the answer I had in the begging (r^2) d^2g/dr^2?

Comment: Correct. Then $r^2\cos^2\varphi$ will become $x^2$ and so on.

Comment: Just write them as they are

Comment: but  if i do this, it will become again in the form it was initially

Comment: I thought that you wanted to show that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side. Simplifying an equality does not make too much sense otherwise. Maybe, if I subtract the right hand side term from both sides, using the derivation from my answer, you can write your expression as $0=0$. Is that what you have in mind? Or to more accurately map to your question, how would you simplify $1+2=3$?

Comment: i do not want to show that is equal. i just have to simplify the expression by change the coordinates from Cartesian to polar. can you tell me how can i do it? maybe i can do it as you said, and just stop where i only have r and φ?

Comment: If you change the coordinates to polar on the left hand side you get the right hand side. Or if you change the right hand side to Cartesian, you get the left hand side (that's what I did)

Comment: btw i had to do it from cartesian to polar coordinates. your answer does not show the opposite?

Comment: Just use the same approach. In principle, from an expression in $x,y$ you get an expression in $r,\varphi$. It will just take more terms, to show that in the expression on the left all the terms corresponding to $\varphi$ will cancel.